# What are the risks of panicking inside an extrinsic call?

Tags: runtime, extrinsic, validator, collator, panic

Let's imagine the following extrinsic.

```
#[pallet::call_index(1)]
#[pallet::weight(T::WeightInfo::might_panic_extrinsic())]
pub fn might_panic_extrinsic(origin: OriginFor<T>) -> DispatchResult {
    let member = ensure_signed(origin)?;
    let might_panic = custom_func().unwrap();
    Ok(())
}
```

What are the risks and consequences, security-wise and considering we are using the latest Substrate version, if my extrinsic panics due to the `unwrap` call ?

Will my node crash ? Will my runtime restart ? Will the extrinsic just be reverted, just like it would be for a custom `Error` ? Is there any security risk that the collator misses his slot ?

Comment: Why do you want to panic and crash when you can just return an error with a simple `?`

Answer (score 1):

Your node's runtime thread will crash, and that extrinsic won't be included in the block.

I recall that Frontier used this to prevent certain invalid extrinsics from being included in the block. (But I'm not sure about this now)

However, it is not recommended to write such code. You must ensure that this is not called in `pallet::hooks`. Panicking in hooks is not allowed, as it will result in your chain becoming brick.

There isn't a significant security risk for an offline collator. However, if all collators go offline, your chain will become unusable. Panic occurring on hooks could lead to this situation.

Comment: Thank you. 
Couldn't that be a way for an attacker to abuse the resources of a collator by spamming that same panicking extrinsic and making the runtime thread restarting over and over ?

Comment: Actually, collator won't expose their nodes RPC. Extrinsic would only affect the RPC service nodes. That's why I said hooks would affect all nodes.